# Git merge-driver on one file called twice when merging

Tags: git, merge, branch

when merging a branch into master, we found a problem that the merge driver called twice on one file.

Here is merge-config

```
[merge "daff-tab"]
    name = daff tabular tab merge
    driver = D：\\tabtool/x64/release/TabTool.exe cui_merge %O %A %B %L %P
```

**1st time**
[image]

**2nd time**
[image]

%Ps are identical(so I think one file merged twice). I notice %L==9 1st time, but %L==7 the 2nd. If there are conflicts, I just write %A "@there are conflicts".

The following code was execute during 1st time to write string "@there are conflicts" to %A.

```
if (conflict) {
    tab_desc_write_invalid(argv[3]);
    return 1;
}
```

I checked the content of .merge_file_a00724 of 2nd time merge-driver called,  just the result of the first merge. My driver cannot recognize such content, which leads to latter merge fails.

WHY during one merge operation, a file is merged twice? it's beyond my knowledge about git.

Besides, when the first time merge-drive called, conflicts caused by .merge_file_*00724 seem to have been resolved before, but it's reopened again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that this particular merge has multiple merge bases and that as a result the merge bases are being merged to produce a new base (a new but temporary commit) suitable as input to the final merge.

To test this theory out, run `git merge-base --all` on the same two commits you fed to the original merge.

If this is the case, you can use the `-s resolve` strategy to alter the merge method: now, instead of merging the multiple merge bases to make a new commit, Git will simply pick one of the multiple merge bases.

Probably better, you can also specify a different driver for the recursive merge.  See the `recursive` setting example in [the gitattributes documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver).  As noted in comments below, recursive merge also [increases the marker size by 2](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5be1f00a9a701532232f57958efab4be8c959a29/ll-merge.c#L384-L388), which explains the 7 vs 9 for `%L`.

Comment: this article informs me criss-cross merge leads to more-than-one merge-base. I hadn't encountered such an issue before.

btw, why %L differs in two merge-driver calls?

Comment: The `%L` thing was a bit of a mystery, but the answer is buried in an undocumented bit in the source code: a recursive merge gets its count increased by 2 (regardless of the recursion depth): https://github.com/git/git/blob/5be1f00a9a701532232f57958efab4be8c959a29/ll-merge.c#L384-L388

Comment: Many thanks, you perfectly answered my question; everything is clear now.